# Way to successfully change Content View?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I have an app that uses this [RibbonMenu](https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu) and I wanted to know if it was possible to use the menu items to change the ContentView of the Activity instead of another activity to reduce the size of my app. I've tried doing this already,and it changed the content view perfectly, but i was not able to press the home button. I'm in a bit of a rush here, but i'll try to post code if anyone asks for it. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu items is UI element. It does nothing by itself. It however can trigger some more actions in your code. As for changing activity layout, yes, you can call `setContentView()` at any time you want.

> to reduce the size of my app

this is not the way optimalizations should be done